# convert readFileSync to createwritestream/ File too large

Tags: javascript, node.js, readfile

I have the following code. The problem I am having is that my text.txt is too large that I get the following error

```
Cannot create a string longer than 0x1fffffe8 character
```

is there a way that I can use fs.createwritestream instead of fs.readFileSync
after I read the file I uses "json" variable to perform some edit on the file. any idea how I can alter the code?

```
let json = convert.xml2js(
  fs.readFileSync(`text.txt`),
  {
    instructionHasAttributes: true,
    compact: true,
    spaces: 4,
    reversible: true,
  }
);
```

Comment: If the file is too large to read into memory, then it will also be too large to parse the whole thing into JSON and have that in memory.  You're going to have to find some way to read/process the file incrementally without keeping the whole thing in memory.  We could better offer you ideas on that if you showed us what the data is like (show a sample piece of the data) and describe what you're trying to accomplish with that data.

Comment: For example, maybe that large a set of data belongs in a database so you can more easily manipulate a piece of it.  Or, if it's a line-based or record-based format, then you could perhaps read a line or record at a time and process them in sequence one at a time, never holding more than a few in memory.  It really depends upon what the data is and what you're trying to do with it.

Comment: The data is in xml file
I convert it to json so I can look for some data and make a call to ldap and then change the data and paste it back to the xml

Comment: ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hibernate-generic datetime="2021-05-12 20:00:51">
<object class="CustomContentEntityObject" package="com.atlassian.confluence.content">
<id name="id">1743782215</id>
<property name="hibernateVersion">2</property>
<property name="title"><![CDATA[editor]]></property>
<property name="lowerTitle"><![CDATA[editor]]></property>
<collection name="bodyContents" class="java.util.Collection"><element class="BodyContent" package="com.atlassian.confluence.core"><id name="id">1743782216</id>

Comment: Well, the data is apparently too large to deal with entirely in memory.  So, you either have to deal with it incrementally one record at a time and find a different stream-like parser that will do that or you have to convert it to a better format for manipulating like put it in a database.

Comment: Take a look at the [xml-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-stream) module that has this in its description: ***"When working with large XML files, it is probably a bad idea to use an XML to JavaScript object converter, or simply buffer the whole document in memory. Then again, a typical SAX parser might be too low-level for some tasks (and often a real pain).  This is why we've rolled our own stream parser that tries to address these shortcomings. It processes an XML stream chunk by chunk and fires events only for nodes of interest, matching them with CSS-like selectors."***